# Calculating the limit of a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I was intrigued by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115793) answer where we say:

$$A^k v_1 := (1,2^{-k}, 4^{-k}), \ A^k v_2 := (1, 2 \cdot2^{-k}, 3 \cdot 4^{-k}),$$

And we want to show that $\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty}$, $\text{span}\{A^k v_1, A^k v_2\} = \{(x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

I'm not quite sure I see how this is the case. I would think we treat them as separate vectors and compute the limit as $k \rightarrow +\infty$, so we would arrive at $\text{span}\{A^k v_1, A^k v_2\} = \text{span}\{(1,0,0)\}$ but I must be missing something in both the formalization / intuition here, since these two linear independent vectors must span a subspace of dimension $2$.

I tried subtracting the vectors and examining the limit but all I can see is that $2*4^{-k}$ goes to $0$ "faster" than $2^{-k}$, which still doesn't resolve much and makes me wonder why $(0,1,0)$ would be considered in the span but not $(0,0,1)$.